# Knockout, evaluate nullability of an observable

Tags: knockout.js

If I have a simple ViewModel with one observable property like this one:

```
var viewModel = function()
{
   var self = this;

   self.myProperty = ko.observable('');

   self.isValid = function(){
      if(!self.myProperty){
         return false;
      }
      return true;
   };
}
```

How can I validate properly the observable and be sure is not null/undefined or empty? It is valid only if the value is different than null/undefined or ''

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knockout observables are functions. You need to call them with no arguments to get their underlying value (this is called unwrapping).

So you just need to write `self.myProperty()` in your `if`:

```
self.isValid = function(){
      if(!self.myProperty()){
         return false;
      }
      return true;
};
```

You can read more about observables in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#reading-and-writing-observables).

Comment: It works perfectly and I should pay more attention to Knockout documentation. 
Thanks!